# Регулярное выражение с исключением слова

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Делаю обработку адресов для сайта.

Есть строка(урл) вида:

```
site.ru/novosti/page-2/
```

Есть первое выражение: `#^/novosti/page-([0-9]+)/#`, которое ловит урл и обрабатывает его.

Но есть другое более приоритетное правило которое не даёт первому сработать.

Второе выражение: `#^/novosti/#`

Задача по идее простая (на сколько я это дело понимаю) - добавить исключение во второе выражение что бы спокойно могло отрабатываться первое. Грубо говоря если во втором выражении после последнего слэша идут символы "`page-`" + любое число до тысячи, то такое выражение должно вернуть `false` или просто не отработать.

Comment: это выражения для htaccess или скрипта?

Comment: Вообще это битрикс обрабатывает, получается для скрипта.

Comment: я не знаю, как роутер битрикса работает, но может достаточно их последовательность поменять?

Comment: а нет, вот в таком направлении можно попробовать

Comment: Пробовал, он сортирует их.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для этих целей в регулярных выражениях существует такая вещь, как [утверждения](http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.assertions.php).

Существует два класса утверждений:

- утверждения назад (*lookbehind*) накладывают ограничения на текст *перед собой*.
- утверждения вперед (*lookahead*) накладывают ограничения на текст *после себя*.

Каждое утверждение может быть как положительными, так и отрицательным. Каждый из видов утверждений записывается по разному:

- Положительное утверждение назад(*positive lookbehind*): `(?<=foo)bar`
- Отрицательное утверждение назад(*negative lookbehind*): `(?<!foo)bar`
- Положительное утверждение вперед(*positive lookahead*): `foo(?=bar)`
- Отрицательное утверждение вперед(*negative lookahead*): `foo(?!bar)`

Например, регулярное выражение с отрицательным утверждением вперед `foo(?!bar)` будет соответствовать строке `foo` за которой не идет строка `bar` (`foofoo`, но не `foobar`).

В вашем конкретном случае регулярное выражение может иметь вид:

```
#^/novosti/(?!page-[0-9]+).*$#
```

А вот и ссылка на [рабочий пример](https://regex101.com/r/eF6aH9/1) на regex101.

Если захватывать *всю* строку не нужно, то можно обойтись вот таким выражением:

```
#^/novosti/(?!page-[0-9]+)#
```

Comment: @peter, это для htaccess выражение или в скрипте можно использовать?

Comment: Это для php, вы же именно такое и хотели.

Comment: @peter
`if (preg_match("#^/novosti/(?!page-[0-9]+).*$#", "site.ru/novosti/page-2/")) {
    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false";
}`
Просто такая конструкция вернет false. Или что-то не правильно делаю?

Comment: @peter, так вам же это и нужно: "_Грубо говоря если во втором выражении после последнего слэша идут символы <...>, то такое выражение должно вернуть `false`_"

Comment: Ну и я не `@peter`, а `@DmitriySimushev` =)

Comment: все верно. Спать уже пора просто)

Answer (score 1):

Если система поддерживает просмотр вперед, то вторую регулярку надо заменить на:

```
#^/novosti/(?!page-[0-9]+)#
```